# BrE. What is the difference between to and for?

Tags: grammar, british-english

For example:
I’ll do it for you OR I’ll do it to you?
My children are everything to me OR My children are everything for me?

Update:
What is the difference between
This gift for you and to you?

Comment: There is no such thing as the difference between to and for with regard to British English or any English, for that matter. I wonder where that idea even comes from....Also, I find the question very odd from what appears to be an English speaker.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the example with children,
`My children are everything to/for me.`,
the word "to" and "for" mean about the same thing.

But "I'll do it **to** you." is very different from "I'll do it **for** you".

With **to**, the sentence means that you will be the object of what I do, and that usually has a negative sense.

With **for**, the sentence mean that you will benefit from the action.

As you can see, the difference between "to" and "for" depends greatly on context. There are tens of thousands of words such as nouns, verbs, adjectives and adverbs in English, but only about 100 prepositions, so the ones we have are used in many different ways.

Comment: What is the difference between This gift for you and to you?

Comment: In such short sentences, there's no difference. You could use  "for" like this: Here is a good gift for you to give her." You could use "to" like this: "This is my gift to you." The possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 1):

If you do something 'for' someone, you are doing something which benefits them.

If you do something 'to' someone, the thing being done is directed towards that person, perhaps being done on their person or just nearby.

The words can both be used in some situations. "Tattoo? I can do that to/for you" -- either is grammatically correct. Doing something 'to' someone is usually regarded as slightly aggressive, and so in the above, 'for' is much more likely to be used. Using 'to' would make it sound like the speaker intended it to be something the recipient would not like to have done.

If the object is not a person, then we're more likely to say 'to' -- "The room needs painting? I can do that to it." or "You need the room painted? I can do that for you."

I'm afraid the rules (so-called) for prepositions in English aren't all that consistent, and native English speakers are mostly unaware of them. We follow the rules by having heard them used all our lives, not because we know what the rules are explicitly.

Comment: I doubt the OP could ask the question without know the answer to it.